# Repeat rows based on vector

Tags: r, repeat, rep

I am trying to repeat rows in R multiple times (how often is determined by a column). My initial code works only sometimes for some reason.

```
start <- c(1901, 1902, 1950, 1980, 1980)
end <- c(1905, 1910, 1951, 1999, 1985)
df <- data.frame(start, end)
df$count <- df$end - df$start
```

I am trying to repeat the rows as many times as the difference between start and end. Each year gets one row (the +1 is necessary, so the start and end year both have a row as well).

The code snippet in question which is working only sometimes is the following:

```
df<- df[rep(rownames(df), df$count +1), ]
```

It sometimes says the "times" argument is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
df[rep(seq_along(df$count), df$count), ]
```

This replicates the sequence `1:length(df$count)` with each of `df$count` times.

Comment: I still get the "invalid 'times' argument" error message

Comment: @H.Stevens - Don't know why.  I used your data, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Where did you insert the 1:length(...) snippet?

Comment: @H.Stevens - `seq_along(df$count)` is the same as `1:length(df$count)`.  I thought it might make more sense to explain it as `1:length(df$count)`

Comment: Ah ok, yes that makes sense. I got it to work somehow. So thanks a lot!